# Planes visible only if selected or hovered and "eye" flag ignored in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I have created empty assembly and got all planes invisible. They are visible only if hovered or selected.

On the following picture `PLANE1` is selected and `Right` plane is hovered, so they are visible.

[image]

Planes `Front` and `Top` are invisible despite they are flagged with "eye" icon, which is evident from blue color in a tree.

How to make planes visible?

Answer (score 1):

Under "View" on the toolbar, make sure "Planes" is selected. Or could just be the software bugging, welcome to SolidWorks lol. Close out, open back up if that doesn't work.